Flutter CallKeep 1.0.0 Migration: Incoming Call Screen Not Showing on Android 14 in Release Mode
I am encountering an issue with my Flutter application after migrating to CallKeep 1.0.0. On Android 14, the incoming call screen does not appear in release mode, although it works perfectly on iOS. In debug mode, the call screen shows up correctly on Android as well.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Verified CallKeep setup and ensured all necessary permissions were granted as per the official documentation.
The incoming call screen displays correctly in debug mode on Android, but not in release mode.
What could be causing this issue? Are there any additional settings or configurations I need to check to ensure the incoming call screen shows up properly in release mode on Android 14?

Verified the CallKeep setup and ensured all necessary permissions were granted according to the official documentation.
Ensured that the incoming call screen was displayed correctly in debug mode on Android.

I expected the call screen to show up correctly in both debug and release modes, just as it does on iOS and in debug mode on Android.
